# Why is TypeScript showing error for unexecutable path?

Tags: typescript

I have this sample code:

```
function func(a?: number, b?: number, c?: number) {
  let allGood: boolean = true;
  
  if(!a) {
    console.log('a is unacceptable, so do something with a')
    allGood = false;
  }

  if(!b) {
    console.log('b is unacceptable, so do something with b')
    allGood = false;
  }

  if(!c) {
    console.log('a is unacceptable, so do something with c')
    allGood = false;
  }

  if(allGood) {
    console.log(a + b + c) // Error: "Object is possibly undefined" showing for a, b and c
  } else {
    console.log('oh no!')
  }
}
```

You can see that the final `allGood` is only true if all `a`, `b` and `c` are not falsy (including `undefined`). But inside that last condition, TypeScript is complaining that each of `a`, `b` and `c` is possibly undefined. What would be the best way to fix this without rechecking truthyness of `a`, `b` and `c` since they are already checked before this condition.

Comment: That's a relatively complicated question to ask the type system. While it's "obvious" with simple reasoning, it involves observing tracking changes to a separate variable (which is akin to executing a program..). It's much easier to ask, and answer, `if (!a && !b && !c)`.

Comment: I might rewrite this code to eliminate the `allGood` variable and move the failing checks and specific handling into the else-branch; or using a scope-breaking construct (`return`) on the invalid cases, which will lead to the expected TS behavior.

Comment: What version of Typescript? I'm replicating and getting no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: control flow narrowing is heuristic in nature and does not account for such correlations between variables.  There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#20497](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20497) requesting support for so-called "branch flags" like your `allGood`.  But it is [probably too complex](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20497#issuecomment-349736848) to implement.

---

Long version:

TypeScript uses [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the apparent types of variables and properties in blocks of code where it can follow that type guards or assignments have occurred.  So, for example, in the following example code, the compiler can see that a truthiness check on `a` will narrow it from `number | undefined` to `number`:

```
if (!a) { } else {
  a + 1; // okay
}
```

But after both the true and false branches of an `if` statement are done, if the control flow from multiple paths joins up again, the compiler will re-join the narrowed types into the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of any narrowings from each branch:

```
let x: number | string | undefined = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 123 : undefined;
// x is number | undefined
if (typeof x === "undefined") {      
  // x is undefined
  x = "hello"; // x is string
} else {
  x += 789; // x is number
}
// x is string | number
x.valueOf(); // okay
```

But note that these narrowings/widenings generally happen *independently* for different variables:

```
let someBoolean: boolean;
let x: number | string | undefined = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 123 : undefined;
// x is number | undefined
if (typeof x === "undefined") {      
  // x is undefined
  x = "hello"; // x is string
  someBoolean = true;
} else {
  x += 789; // x is number
  someBoolean = false;
}
// x is string | number
x.valueOf(); // okay
someBoolean; // boolean
```

At the end of this block, `someBoolean` is `boolean` (equivalent to the the union `true | false`), and `x` is `string | number`.  Now it turns out that `someBoolean` and `x` are *correlated* to each other; `someBoolean` cannot be `true` while `x` is a `number`, and `someBoolean` cannot be `false` while `x` is a `string`.  But the compiler *does not track* such correlations.  It treats them as *uncorrelated* or *independent* union types, and therefore assumes that such impossible situations are possible.

I opened [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) to highlight this as a pain point that people run into, but there's no obvious solution that would work.

In order to keep track of correlations automatically and in general, the compiler would have to start doing computations that amount to simulating every possible narrowing of every union-typed variable or property it considers.  For every additional variable or property, this would multiply the amount of compiler work by some factor.  And so compile times would grow exponentially in the number of variables and properties.  So this can't happen.

One could imagine a way to ask the compiler to consider a manually specified set of variables or properties, as suggested in the closed [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051), so that you only pay a performance penalty when it's worth it to you.  That suggestion was closed for a number of reasons, including how unidiomatic it would be to wrap your function body in something like `type switch (a, b, c) { ... }`.

And there is a specific request at [microsoft/TypeScript#20497](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20497) to support "branch flags" like `allGood` that keep track of specific conditions.  But again, there's no obvious way to implement it and maintain reasonable compiler performance.

---

Epilogue:

You will have to just work around this; either by using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you know more about the types of `a`, `b`, and `c` than it does:

```
if (allGood) {
  console.log(a! + b! + c!) // assertions
} else {
  console.log('oh no!')
}
```

(Here I have used the [non-null assertion operator `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) as a more terse version of `(a as number) + (b as number) + (c as number)`)

Or by refactoring to a version that does not rely on such correlated variables, such as something like the (admittedly weird):

```
function func(a?: number, b?: number, c?: number) {

  let good = (a: number) => (b: number) => (c: number) => () => console.log(a + b + c);

  let aGood;
  if (!a) {
    console.log('a is unacceptable, so do something with a')
  } else {
    aGood = good?.(a);
  }

  let abGood;
  if (!b) {
    console.log('b is unacceptable, so do something with b')
  } else {
    abGood = aGood?.(b)
  }

  let abcGood;
  if (!c) {
    console.log('c is unacceptable, so do something with c')
  } else {
    abcGood = abGood?.(c)
  }

  if (abcGood) {
    abcGood();
  } else {
    console.log('oh no!')
  }
}

func(1, 2, 3) // 6;
func(1) // b unacceptable, c unacceptable, oh no!
```

Obviously in this case, the assertions are less obtrusive, so that would be my suggestion here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJIBmArsPAC4CWA9sGZfABQgD8AXEsOWACMIAJwA0SAd178hYpPCl9BIgJR4iJEhgjUkmDAHF69ACY8Bx7SCYBeJNWHkIAbiIbNtUklYBCEGoJiTRJ4Rih6bQA6DHoAc1YAchAkWigkSgREGGoQAW1xcKQTeiRwyGoAC1pgWKQAd1pKvQSVd2D9I1MkO1JMKBc2pABfJAgMfvUg9qQAaiQARmckAHplpHoAaxAAT0GhtymkbV0yiAAhSwhrc0vrV0PjpAAPHiVZJAAfUodq2q-KEwQUjVCAmbpIACyIEqkWE1mKYFYagAPEgAAyRACsSA4CwATABmJA8AFAkEme7BVbPFJpN4iT7pYCA4HAUGDTzeajbGAQeheJ7dGx2ABEpNZoJFAWCJEGJGpgtSTJZ5LlNNFFTGMRFSwVtO+wl+atOFwiV1s9kcA0OIzGE0CMppMzsAHYABwATl1a0VdJkImN9EgpqsFt642twX2hz1SqgPxqjPpwkGT0iADdME4APKkJHe9ZbXaHE23YAFixm6wHYKc3wCAJq0LAcJRGLxBICfUZeBZHJ5CAFErFUpBnRVRMNJoCFpqjrGME9PqRzTRjleXzwRuHEJhM3ROKJZJKnt93L5UdFEqnSq-eqNCryWc7vQYQwL8Hh-qU1c1jwb+dTG3R1m1bCAD3iZI5i7OYtxWNYAFFhGEehhB4EVswEAArCAaH1GB6CgKBaDybZlTJNkTBFUoKnoBpE1IVC9HELt4XkPZRgjSYQL3NtDwSehH2AegfGfKN3DXIJQEgWAEGQABBIiRDoRhuM0CgqBUpgNLYThXn9ORJH05Q5AUYzZGAmVHkAswJDLcEHCce41TrPxLJ4lt93bI9u1AXsIGyc9B0vEcbwnWop0fEAxMdV93y6JcIx-cTCBcjcfAbNSPLAiDEi7E8-LPAchyvUdynC+9pxix0bM-Zdkt-VKX1cuCHVi0CvP4480lPAL+wvQpQrHW9JwfJ9WhfEhasS781Ukx06xs9yZQ6vjIJ8WYJA22CfDUakQCU4QtLmzj7TVXdPLWxJBN4ETqsalKSHm3hwGgOBECQAAlIEEGoJi2pIHStOYKh2EUAyWPBkzxDM6QTO3NVHliD87HYczVG6AA+bwBHR4Q1BsbHWHgPGCaJsn5F48DvKgiRNq3ZyX2szoKTS7w3KylaqdypJfMyPqgpKobyrvSLmgmx1bS4gGZRAFnwWR0wOEidgVAap6-2CayBBZ9WUnSzKZeCVbqf4-KesKgXipC69hoqsWZwlmUpbOya9B1lG9BZ5XWAbObNc0bX4F1tnN2W43ue8hJ4D5-zAutwbbZF0amnge6ntO5Ajc0XJg893JvZVrd-aahaAIEPOgM59oK5Z-MTrtLPzspy7TY7G7hNEp3HsawYdNYeZxDxcQCT2tYADYGv7+Yx7p3r44vGP5-64KO5EiSDiGIA)